# How do I repair a VMWare Disk file?

Tags: windows-7, repair, vmdk

I have a copy of Ubuntu 16.04 (guest) running in VMWare Workstation (11.1.3 build-3206955) on Windows 7 (host).  I recently was working and received the following message.

> The operation on file "C:\Users\mcdonaldd\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu 64 (2016)\Ubuntu 64 (2016)-s005.vmdk" failed.
>
> If the file resides on a remote file system, make sure that the network connection and the server where this disk resides are functioning properly. If the file resides on removable media, reattach the media.
>
> Select Retry to attempt the operation again.
>
> Select Cancel to end this session.
>
> Select Continue to forward the error to the guest operating system.

[image]

the file isn't on a remote file system... which is sort of confusing. Doing "Retry" and "Continue" didn't seem to do anything and the alert showed back up.  So I hit "Cancel" and it closed out the machine.  I'm trying to repair the file using the following command; however, I just get the response below.  Can anyone instruct me on how to resolve this issue? Thanks!

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation>vmware-vdiskmanager -R "C:\Users\mcdonaldd\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu 64 (2016)\Ubuntu 64 (2016)-s005.vmdk"
VixDiskLib: Invalid configuration file parameter. Failed to read configuration file.

C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation>vmware-vdiskmanager -R "C:\Users\mcdonaldd\Documents\Virtual Machines\Ubuntu 64 (2016)\Ubuntu 64 (2016)-s005.vmdk"
```

[image]

**Edit:**
If I try to copy/past the file to a different directory I'll get the following alert in Windows 7.

> Can't read from the source file or disk.
>
> Ubutnu 64 (2016)-s005.vmdk
>   Type: VMware virtual disk file
>   Size: 675 MB
>   Date modified: 3/17/2016 10:51 AM

[image]

**Edit 2:**
I tried running chkdsk to see if there were any errors and it came up with none.

```
CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  320768 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  1645 large files processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  2 EA records processed.
  92 reparse records processed.
CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
  406032 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
  0 unindexed files recovers.
CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
  320768 file SDs/SIDs processed.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  42633 data files processed.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  39131152 USN bytes processed.
Usn Journal verification completed.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

 476042239 KB total disk space.
 359298748 KB in 247318 files.
    147996 KB in 42634 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    441295 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 116154200 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 119010559 total allocation units on disk.
  29038550 allocation units available on disk.
```

**Edit 3:**
Once I schedule chkdsk to run on my computer once restarted this message happens and wont allow me to...

```
Checking file system on C:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is OS.

A disk check has been scheduled.
Windows will now check the disk.
Cannot open volume for direct access.
Autochk cannot run due to an error caused by a recently installed software
package.
Use the system restore feature from the control panel to restore the system
 to a point prior to the
recent software package installation.
An unspecified error occured (766f6c756d652e63 3f1).
```

**Edit 4:**
I've removed the drive and hooked it up to another computer... ran chkdsk and everything came back with no errors. Just updating the post with this information.

I managed to "repair" the vmdk disk. I first ran a debug command on the main vmdk drive.  It then directed me to one of the specific files in that directory having an error.  That then allowed me to run the `-R` command on it and correct that.  I then defragged the disk - just in case - and now I'm trying to update the Ubuntu system again to see if it errors out.

**Edit 5:**

Still errors out...

Comment: Hi fwaokda. I edited your question to include the pure text from the console applications instead of the images, and include the text from the images for the graphical prompts, to make the question more searchable.

Comment: From the information provided, I would say that this looks like an imminent (if not even actual) disk failure. Check the SMART data for any indication of problems, check all cabling to and from the drive, and make sure you have up to date backups.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, oh good thinking- never even crossed my mind. Thanks!